# node.js huge slow down when array exceeds a certain size limit

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, node.js

I ran into an issue where I am using a library called postcss and it is tokenizing the css and putting those tokens in the array. If the number of tokens is the array is 114456 the code executes instantaneously but if I add one more selector which adds few more token totaling 114468 tokens in the array then the same code slows down a lot. The tokens are exactly the same and it is not going in a different code path.

Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/ankurp/e64e9aa2dbcfe0350963 In the gist the code being called is the function and the two css files are shown. The slow one has one more css selector than the other one.

The issue seems to start if array is greater than 114456. Is that some magic number in nodejs and are there techniques to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a solution to speed up the function by instantiating the array using `Array()` rather than `[]` but not sure why this small difference leads to a slowdown from a second to about a minute.